# WebSocket does not append HTML on message

Tags: jquery, arrays, websocket, frontend

Problem: WebSocket does not behave how I expect it. I want it to append a message to the DOM each time a message is received creating a row of divs without having to refresh the page.

What's actually happening: I am receiving array data and the data is being appended correctly to the page but I have to refresh my browser in order to see it. The data comes in on a json string one time but is updated continually from the server. I only get one event message of an array that updates continually so I thought that socket.onmessage was working ONLY once so I made it send if the length of the array was more than 3. When the message was received on the client, it still did not update until refresh which makes me assume it's a front end issue.

index.html

```
socket.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    const keywordsList = JSON.parse(e.data);
    for (const i in keywordsList){
    $('#keywordsList').append("<div>" + keywordsList[i] + "</div>");
  }
};
```

The server: (I don't think it's relevant since I am getting data to the front end)

```
const wsServer = new ws.Server({ noServer: true });
wsServer.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('open', message => message);
  if (keywordsList.length>3){
  socket.send(JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, keywordsList)));
  }
});
```

Again, everything is working correctly except that I still need to refresh the page to see the HTML displayed.

Thank you.

Comment: Whats the content of `keywordsList`?

Comment: I guess I should mention now that for some reason, I get cannot get / error on my server side but the data still sends. If that is an issue for why this won't work, I do not know but it's worth mentioning that something still is wrong with my websocket.

Comment: It is an array I push from the server to the client filled with strings.